# Check for null for struct in C# if struct isn't nullable

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have some generic method

```
T SomeMethod(Func<T> func){
   T result = func();
     if (result != null)
       { //.....}
}
```

It  works good if `T` is class. But what should I do if `T` is struct? How can I check if `result == default(T)` in case if `T` is `struct`?

P.S. I don't want to use the constraint `where T: class` or `Nullable` types.

Comment: What is the use of checking if a value type is equal to the default value, and how does this logically match an object being `null`?  What if a reference type has just been constructed - is that equivalent?  I think this can't be answered generically, but must be answered on a case-by-case basis depending on your scenario.

Comment: To add to @dlev `default(T) where T : class == null`

Comment: To expand on my earlier comment, if you're just trying to avoid an NRE, then JaredPar's answer tells you that you can simply write `if(result != null)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `T` is compiled to be a `struct` then the comparison with `null` will always evaluate to `false`.  This is covered in section 7.9.6 of the C# language spec

> If an operand of a type parameter type T is compared to null, and the runtime type of T is a value type, the result of the comparison is false.

Comment: Interestingly when you compare nullable structs with `null` it still returns `null`.

Comment: Which version of the spec did you use? I read: "If B is a type parameter and at runtime the type parameter is a nullable type or reference type, 
the result is as if the operand of type B is boxed and then compared to null. " [ECMA 4th ed]

Comment: @CodeInChaos I'm reading the C# 3.5 language spec for reference here

Comment: @CodeInChaos: This is behavior that is specific to `Nullable<T>` (which is a struct itself), as is the ability to assign `null`. That's baked into the language (and perhaps the runtime; I'm not certain about that) and isn't something that can be duplicated on user types.

Comment: @JaredPar, do you mean `if (result != null || result==false)` ? Does it work for structs?

Comment: @AlexMaslakov the comparison `result == false` will fail to compile.  My comment is that the comparison `result != null` will always be `true` when `T` is a `struct`

Comment: +1 because this matches my guess at why you'd want this type of code to begin with.  Testing a non-nullable value type against the default value (`result == default(T)`) is not the same thing as checking if a reference type isn't `null`.

Answer (score 3):

A more idiomatic way of doing this would be to follow the lead of things like `int.TryParse`.

```
public delegate bool TryFunction<T>(out T result);

T SomeMethod(TryFunction<T> func)
{
    T value;

    if(func(out value))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't follow `int.TryParse`'s lead, but instead builds on it.  I don't think this is idiomatic, but it isn't a bad idea.  Whether it generically solves the original problem or just side-steps it is a different question (one I can't answer - check my comment on the OP, since I think the question can't be answered generically).

Comment: `Func<out T, bool>` won't compile. You would have to create new delegate type for that.

Comment: @svick: Good catch; I'm not in front of VS right now. Nonetheless, this should do the trick.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: I'm curious how it doesn't "follow its lead". The common idea is to move the return value into an `out` parameter and return a `bool` indicating success. I'm calling it idiomatic because this technique is used in several places in the framework, and seems to fit the bill.

Comment: @Adam: Wasn't me w/ the downvote.  I'm just being pedantic, wanting some more clarity on exactly which parts are idiomatic.  The signature of the delegate is idiomatic (try-method), but taking a try-method, generic or not, and using it as a predicate isn't idiomatic.  Tho it might be a good idea.

Comment: @Adam: +1; I re-read the question, and I upvoted because you provide a good solution.  I rat holed on the `result == default(T)` part of the OP not making much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using default(T):

```
private T SomeMethod<T>(Func<T> func)
{
  var result = func();
  if (result.Equals(default(T)))
  {
    // handling ...
    return default(T);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: If `T` is a reference type, this will throw a `NullReferenceException`.